# Need Help Sorting Index/Matched Formuals

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am using the `Index` and `Match` function in Excel to create a dynamic list of vendors and the amount of customers that they have.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$9999, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$34:G34, $D$2:$D$9999), 0)),"")
```

alongside with a `COUNTIF` column to create a listing.

However, with this setup it doesn't allow me to sort in descending order.

Would anyone have any ideas how I could make this sort from lowest to highest on this dynamic list?

This is in Excel and I have tried using some form of `RANK` or `VLOOKUP` `MIN` function, but I just can't seem to figure this issue out.

My main goal is to have it so when someone enters a new vendor it will automatically add them to the list which I made work with the code above, but I'm also looking to figure out how to list in descending order.

Thank you!

Comment: What excel version are you using?

Comment: If you’re using excel 365 (recent version), there are new array functions:  https://www.pryor.com/blog/excel-sort-formulas-how-to-sort-dynamic-data/ or if you use a previous version, check this article: https://www.pryor.com/blog/excel-sort-formulas-how-to-sort-dynamic-data/

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I am using Excel 2016 Professional

Comment: Then check the second link

Comment: You can do this easily in a pivot table if that's an option.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-array formula in remove duplicate and sort in descending order

In `G35`, copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$9999,MATCH(0,MMULT(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$9999,">"&$D$2:$D$9999),1)-SUM(MMULT(COUNTIF($G$34:G34,$D$2:$D$9999),1)),0)),"")
```